# Scraping HTML page for contents of div and passing it to a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I need to scrape a web page for a JSON string which rests inside a `div` with a "json-data" `id`. The JSON string is **not** on the same page as the jQuery code itself, so I first need to get the page (using .get?), find the div (using something) and then parse it to JSON :(

I need to parse the contents of that `div` as a JSON object and pass it to a variable so I can use it later in the code.

I have to use jQuery v1.8.3, but I suppose `.get()` and `.load()` work. I'm just not sure how to grab the JSON and put it in a variable.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example using jQuery 1.8.3, as you asked. Quite simple!

I put an example JSON string in a `#json-data` element, then read the element's contents with jQuery's `.html()` and parsed the string with `JSON.parse()`.

```js
$.get( "ajax/test.html", function( data ) {
    var myJson = JSON.parse( $(data).find('#json-data').html() );

    console.log('glossary.title:', myJson.glossary.title)
});
```

```html
<!-- HTML for ajax/test.html page -->
<div id="json-data">
  { "glossary": { "title": "example glossary", "GlossDiv": { "title": "S", "GlossList": { "GlossEntry": { "ID": "SGML", "SortAs": "SGML", "GlossTerm": "Standard Generalized Markup Language", "Acronym": "SGML", "Abbrev": "ISO 8879:1986", "GlossDef": { "para":
  "A meta-markup language, used to create markup languages such as DocBook.", "GlossSeeAlso": ["GML", "XML"] }, "GlossSee": "markup" } } } } }
</div>
```

Comment: or sice we're using old jQuery, you could do the opposite `$.parseJSON(document.getElementById('json-data'))`

Comment: I guess I forgot to mention that the JSON object I'm trying to parse isn't on the same page :s

Comment: Is it on the same domain? If so, you can get the page contents with AJAX via jQuery.

Comment: Same domain, yes. How would I go on about that?

Comment: @Fredrik I've updated my answer. Let me know how this works out.

Comment: Nope, still nothing.. I think a better approach for me would be to just create a cached scraper in nodejs and use it up on this system, instead of running a bunch of jquery scripts in an outdated version and wrestling with more of this.

Thanks a lot, though

Comment: No problem. If you throw up that code on your server and link us to the page, I could try to debug it, but otherwise good luck. :)